# JNDI - Glassfish JDBC, error when referencing data source

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

On a glassfish server I have a JDBC Connection pool set up for my postgresql database. I have also create a JDBC Resource on my Glassfish server for this Connection pool

If I create a web app that I deploy and run on this Glassfish server I get the following message about the jdbc resource. (IDE is Eclipse)

```
[#|2011-10-03T13:33:09.745+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=132;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|This web app [GlassfishTest] has no expand »resource environment reference by the name of [jdbc/MEM_Reporting]|#]
```

In my web.xml the resource is configured as follows:

```
<resource-env-ref>
<resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</resource-env-ref-name>
<jndi-name>reporting</jndi-name>
</resource-env-ref>
```

I have been searching for a while now but cant find any solution, hope any of you guyz can help out.

Comment: Have you mapped your reference in `sun-web.xml` as well?  Also, what is the name that you've used for your JDBC resource?

Comment: did you try restarting your server after creating the resource? it looks to me that the configuration data is correct but the resource doesn't exist...

Comment: I just noticed, I mapped it in my sun-web.xml, not web.xml. The project doesnt have a web.xml.

Comment: @Alex I have restarted it several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you've be using resource-ref instead of resource-env-ref?

UPDATE:

How do you reference it? Did you try to reference it with "java:comp/env/jdbc/MEM_Reporting"

also in  web.xml resource-ref should look ike

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

in sun-web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</res-ref-name>
     <jndi-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</jndi-name>
 </resource-ref>
```

Also, take a look at
[Sun documentation for Reference Elements](http://wikis.sun.com/display/WebServerdocs/Reference+Elements#ReferenceElements)

Comment: I just changed those lines to:

  <resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</res-ref-name>
   <jndi-name>jdbc/MEM_Reporting</jndi-name>
   
  </resource-ref>

But I got the same error

Comment: In my sun-web.xml resource-ref has to contain res-ref-name, jndi-name, and default-resource-principal. Not the fields that you listed in your update. I have tried those as well but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: That last update did it :) silly project had no web.xml, just a sun-web.xml.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I add `<jndi-name>` tag in glassfish-web.xml file, not in sun-web.xml and after that the warning dissapear.